# Pandas: add dataframes to dataframe - match on index and column value

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to add pandas dataframes to another dataframe with different lengths such that the values in the result are aligned with both the (time)index and a key value from a column that is present in all dataframes.

Say I want to combine df1,df2 and df3 and merge on index and column 'id':

```
df1
            id value1
2015-05-01   1     13
2015-05-01   2     14
2015-05-02   1     15
2015-05-02   2     16

df2
            id  value2
2015-05-01   1       4
2015-05-02   1       5

df3
            id  value2
2015-05-01   2       7
2015-05-02   2       8
```

What I would like is to get a dataframe that looks like

```
df
            id   value1 value2
2015-05-01   1       13      4
2015-05-01   2       14      7
2015-05-02   1       15      5
2015-05-02   2       16      8
```

but I struggle with the merge function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataFrames look like this:

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,1,2], 'value1':[13,14,15,16]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-5-1', '2015-5-1', '2015-5-2', '2015-5-2']))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1], 'value2':[4,5]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-5-1', '2015-5-2']))
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,2], 'value2':[7,8]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-5-1', '2015-5-2']))
```

you could concatenate all the DataFrames:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
#             id  value1  value2
# 2015-05-01   1      13     NaN
# 2015-05-01   2      14     NaN
# 2015-05-02   1      15     NaN
# 2015-05-02   2      16     NaN
# 2015-05-01   1     NaN       4
# 2015-05-02   1     NaN       5
# 2015-05-01   2     NaN       7
# 2015-05-02   2     NaN       8
```

Since the result is being aligned on both the date and the `id`, it's natural to set `id` as an index. Then if we stack the DataFrame we get this Series:

```
series = df.set_index(['id'], append=True).stack()
#             id        
# 2015-05-01  1   value1    13
#             2   value1    14
# 2015-05-02  1   value1    15
#             2   value1    16
# 2015-05-01  1   value2     4
# 2015-05-02  1   value2     5
# 2015-05-01  2   value2     7
# 2015-05-02  2   value2     8
# dtype: float64
```

Now if we turn around and unstack the Series, the values are aligned based on the remaining index -- the date and the `id`:

```
result = series.unstack()
```

yields

```
               value1  value2
           id                
2015-05-01 1       13       4
           2       14       7
2015-05-02 1       15       5
           2       16       8
```

Note that `unstack()` requires that the remaining index is unique. That means
that there are no duplicate `(date, id)` entries. If there are duplicate entries, then its not clear what the desired output should be. One way to address the issue would be to group by the `date` and `id` and aggregate the values. Another option would be to pick one value and drop the others.

Comment: But what do I do if 'value' is a new column to be added and I do not want to do any group operations?

Comment: In your Q above, please add actual values to your `df1` and show the desired output.

Comment: I added values as requested. Note that 'value2' is the same column in both df2 and df3, but different from value1 in df1. I hope this is getting clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I also found out that I could replicate the above result if I convert all dataframe indices to a pd.MultiIndex (date, id) and then simply do `df = df1.join(df2).join(df3)`

Comment: It sounds like your real dataframes must be somehow different than the example posted here, since here `df1.join(df2).join(df3)` raises a `ValueError: columns overlap...` exception.

Comment: My bad: `df = df1.join(df2).combine_first(df3)`