# pandas : create column from the indices of a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing two dataframes (Small_df and Big_df). Both dataframes have a time column. Big_df time column is chronologically ordered with a timestep of 10 seconds, while Small_df time column does not have a fix timestep. Some of time values within Big_df exist within Small_df, sometimes more than once.

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a new column within Small_df that holds the indices of the rows within Big_df that have matching time values. 
Here is the structure of both dataframes: (Note that the time is in Timestamp format)

Small_df :

```
print(Small_df['Date'].head())
0   2019-05-22 15:37:05
1   2019-05-22 15:40:25
2   2019-05-22 15:40:45
3   2019-05-22 15:40:45
4   2019-05-22 15:41:55
```

Big_df :

```
print(Big_df['Date'].head())
0    2019-05-22 15:20:25
1    2019-05-22 15:20:35
2    2019-05-22 15:20:45
3    2019-05-22 15:20:55
4    2019-05-22 15:21:05
```

We can find the corresponding times of what is shown for Small_df at this location in Big_df :

```
print(Big_df['Date'].iloc[100:130])
100    2019-05-22 15:37:05
101    2019-05-22 15:37:15
102    2019-05-22 15:37:25
103    2019-05-22 15:37:35
104    2019-05-22 15:37:45
105    2019-05-22 15:37:55
106    2019-05-22 15:38:05
107    2019-05-22 15:38:15
108    2019-05-22 15:38:25
109    2019-05-22 15:38:35
110    2019-05-22 15:38:45
111    2019-05-22 15:38:55
112    2019-05-22 15:39:05
113    2019-05-22 15:39:15
114    2019-05-22 15:39:25
115    2019-05-22 15:39:35
116    2019-05-22 15:39:45
117    2019-05-22 15:39:55
118    2019-05-22 15:40:05
119    2019-05-22 15:40:15
120    2019-05-22 15:40:25
121    2019-05-22 15:40:35
122    2019-05-22 15:40:45
123    2019-05-22 15:40:55
124    2019-05-22 15:41:05
125    2019-05-22 15:41:15
126    2019-05-22 15:41:25
127    2019-05-22 15:41:35
128    2019-05-22 15:41:45
129    2019-05-22 15:41:55
```

And the outcome I am looking for would be something like this :

```
print(Small_df[['Date','Big_df_idx']].head())
0   2019-05-22 15:37:05   100
1   2019-05-22 15:40:25   120
2   2019-05-22 15:40:45   122
3   2019-05-22 15:40:45   122
4   2019-05-22 15:41:55   129
```

I can get the corresponding indices for the matching values, by doing this :

```
Big_df_idx = Big_df[Big_df['Date'].isin(Small_df['Date'].astype(str).tolist())].index

print(Big_df_idx[0:10])
 Int64Index([100, 120, 122, 129, 153, 156, 159, 160, 177, 178], dtype='int64')
```

However, this only returns the indices once, while I would need something that can account for repeated indices.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: add dataframes to dataframe - match on index and column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507442/pandas-add-dataframes-to-dataframe-match-on-index-and-column-value)

Comment: what will you do with the index values in the new column in `Small_df`?

Comment: @jeschwar I will do +1 with them and get the subsequent timestep of Big_df and then replace the Small_df time column with this updated time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform the task run:

```
pd.merge(Small_df, Big_df.reset_index().rename(
    columns={'index': 'Big_df_idx'}), how='left')
```

The key to success is to copy the index of `Big_df` into a regular column
and rename it to `Big_df_idx`.

Such a temporary DataFrame is then merged with `Small_df`, in *left* mode,
to get only dates from `Small_df`, but with corresponding indices from
`Big_df` column.

Comment: Fascinating. I just had to add .astype(str) to Small_df and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On relatively small data instead of creating new DataFrame object you can use `map()` function to solve your problem:

```
Small_df['id'] = Small_df['Date'].map(dict(zip(Big_df['Date'], Big_df.index)))
```